# indexing with multidimensional key pandas error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as the following:

```
A   B  C  D  E
g1  1 -10 20 text1
g2  0  0  0  text2
g3  0  1  0  text3
g4  0  0  0  text4
```

I want to filter out g2 & g4 where all of 'B', 'C', 'D' values are 0

I tried

`df = df[df[['B','C','D']]==0]` returns output same as input,

`df = df[df[['B','C','D']].all(axis=1)==0]` also returns output same as input,

`df = df.loc[df[['B','C','D']].isin(['0'])]` returns 'Cannot index with multi-dimensional key.

The expected output is,

```
A   B  C  D  E
g1  1 -10 20 text1
g3  0  1  0  text3
```

What is the error here?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were closest with your second attempt. Compare to zero before you use `all`. Then take the negative via the `~` operator:

```
mask = (df[['B', 'C', 'D']] == 0).all(1)
df = df[~mask]

print(df)

    A  B   C   D      E
0  g1  1 -10  20  text1
2  g3  0   1   0  text3
```

To understand how this logic works, notice that comparing a dataframe to a scalar returns a Boolean dataframe:

```
print(df[['B', 'C', 'D']] == 0)

       B      C      D
0  False  False  False
2   True  False   True
```

You can then collapse by dimension 1 via [`pd.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html). The syntax and methods are borrowed from NumPy array functionality.